# Rails ERB view syntax issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I apparently can't get the syntax proper here:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="<%= #{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/image.png %>">
```

What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: IMO the *more* appropriate way would be to use stylesheets and assets appropriately.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

UPDATE:

Answer below shows correct syntax, but to display image path it is better to use @TomFeaks answer.

try this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="<%= "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/image.png" %>">
```

Comment: You will probably have to use single quotes inside the double quotes.

Comment: Ugh; there are helpers for this, and should be preferred to anything like this.

Comment: This code actually **does not work** - the direct path to the file on disk is not accessible to a browser using http.

Comment: I only wanted to provide solution to a syntax problem - I agree that @TomFakes answer is better in terms of including path to the image. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Rails provides asset helpers to get the path of image files, and that works with the Asset Pipeline and automatically works when you change the asset_host to use a CDN.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="<%= image_path('image.png') %>">
```

Here's the documentation on [Asset Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)